# Converting dec to binary, octal and hex problem

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, hex, octal

The task is on Hackerrank. Print 3 numbers in their binary, octal and hex. Numbers must be below 10^6 or end the program. There are 2 Test Cases. I've done the Test Case #0, but I don't know what else to fix for Test Case #1. I think I've done all the things that the task wants from me. Can you help me solve this?

> Test Case #0
>
> Input: 2 8 15
>
> Output: 10 2 2
>
> 1000 10 8
>
> 1111 17 F

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string decimal_to_binary(int n)
{
       string m;
       while (n >= 1) 
       {
             m = static_cast<char>((n%2) + '0') + m;
             n /=2;
       }
       return m;
}

int main()
{
unsigned long long a,b,c;

    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if(a > 1000000 || b > 1000000 || c > 1000000) {return 0;}
    else{ 
    cout << std::dec << decimal_to_binary(a) << " " << std::oct << a << " " 
<< std::uppercase << std::hex << a << '\n'
        << std::dec << decimal_to_binary(b) << " " << std::oct << b << " " 
<< std::uppercase << std::hex << b << '\n'
        << std::dec << decimal_to_binary(c) << " " << std::oct << c << " " 
<< std::uppercase << std::hex << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

Edit: pasting the actual task description below

> Write a program to convert a number to binary, octal and
> hexadecimal.
>
> Input Format
>
> The standard input is set to a number of numbers (recorded in a
> decimal number system) of less than 10 ^ 6.
>
> Constraints
>
> .
>
> Output Format
>
> For each number from the input of a single line of the standard
> output, three numbers (one interval between them) are output - a
> record of this number in binary, octal and hexadecimal numeral
> systems.
>
> Sample Input 0
>
> 2 8 15 Sample Output 0
>
> 10 2 2 1000 10 8 1111 17 F

Comment: Why do you use 3 variables instead of simple loop?

Comment: "Numbers must be below 10^6 or end the program." your `if` accepts 10^6 which contradicts that condition.

Comment: @Slava There are three variables because the program should not produce any output if any one of them is too big.

Comment: Please post the actual task description. Don't paraphrase.

Comment: @molbdnilo then there should be array and 2 loops but not copy pasted code.

Comment: @molbdnilo I've pasted the actual task description.

Comment: @Slava I tried making the program to not accept 10^6 and it still didn't work. 999,999

Comment: Here's the url to the task: bitDOTly/2K4N8Fr

Comment: The description does not say that the input is exactly three numbers - you're given "a number of numbers". It also states that the numbers you're given will be less than 10^6, not that you should exit if they are greater.

Comment: @molbdnilo How can I make when I don't know the amount of numbers to be passed ?

Comment: @Nedko You read, and process, one number at a time until there are no more numbers. Check the introduction to streams in your favourite C++ book.